# Build v8 javascript engine on windows

Tags: windows, v8, gyp

trying to install v8 on Windows XP visual sudio 2010, 
I followed instruction on project site https://developers.google.com/v8/build but could not get 'build\gyp_v8'

Could any of you be kind enough to guide me through proper procedure?

Comment: What error do you get? What is the command you run? You also followed the Visual Studio instructions on this page: http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP Also notice a comment at the top of that page: Build issues? File a bug at code.google.com/p/v8/issues or ask for help on v8-users@googlegroups.com.

Comment: actually when i used svn to download gyp on my machine it created build built directory empty, so i was confused where to get gyp_v8 or to built it myself, anyways I browse the code online and found required files in built corresponding built directory and copied those files. Now all.sln is generated.       -Thank you for reply